# Spring ResourceBundleMessageSource - getting no output?

Tags: java, spring, jsf

I'm trying to set up Spring ResourceBundleMessageSource, like this.

```
<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:text" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
</bean>
```

usage in xhtml:

```
... xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/tags">
teststring should be here: <spring:message code="label.name" />
```

result:
I'm getting no output. The property just seams not to be fetched.

resource file is placed under: `src/main/resources/text.properties`

What am I doing wrong?
ty